# JQuery not appending div tag with attributes from a JS function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, oop

I'm trying to print out a block onto the browser window using JQuery. I made the block attributes into a JS object class via function. In this code I am using the `"use strict";` method.

The HTML(5):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><TITLE>Logo Experiment</TITLE>

<head>
<!--adding JQuery library-->
<!--this is a DESKTOP JQuery, so this will not work much on the modern androids-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--setting charset to utf-8 unicode in case symbols are needed-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<style>
body {
display: block;
}
.bx { /* the box... */
background-image: url("metal.png");
background-size: cover;
background-color: #333333; /* in case the image fails to load */
border-width: 1.5px;
border-radius: 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #222222;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #111111;
}
</style>

<body>

<script>
//the script below
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The JS/JQuery:

```
"use strict";

function Box(width, height, style) {//box object
width = this.width;
height = this.height;
style = this.style;
};

var lbx = new Box(256, 256, "bx"); //"lbx" is "logo box"

$(document).ready(function(){//appending a div to the <body> tag directly
$("<div class='" + lbx.style + "' style='width:" + lbx.width + "px;height:" + lbx.height + "px;'>").appendTo("body");
});
```

Whenever I try to append the block with JQuery using the JS object attributes, I end up with this output: `<div class="undefined" style="width:undefinedpx;height:undefinedpx;"></div>`

Any help is much appreciated.

Sincerely, CA1K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it backwards here. It should be `this.parameter = paramter`:

```
function Box(width, height, style) {//box object
width = this.width;
height = this.height;
style = this.style;
};
```

Like this:

```
function Box(width, height, style) {//box object
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.style = style;
    };
```

The first way does nothing other than setting the call arguments to undefined (since none of the properties there are defined).